# Tensorflow results across platforms

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, google-colaboratory

I am experimenting on a two layered network to solve a regression problem (2 Input/ 1 Output). Results from Google's Colab and from Respberry Pi are way too different. It's just the exact code and same train & test data points.

Is it natural to be different or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share a notebook showing your code? Also, do describe the difference you observe, and how you're training things on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)

model.compile(loss= 'mse' ,optimizer=adam, metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=800, batch_size=16)